# Is it possible to create an exposed kubernetes service based on a new deployment in one command?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, cluster-computing, microservices

I feel this must be possible but haven't managed to find docs on how to do this.

I would ideally like to add service exposure details in a deployment yaml file and the service would come up with a host name and port upon the issuing of a create command with the deployment yaml.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question - you can put the definition of the Service in the same file as the Deployment manifest (separated by `---`) and then you can run `kubectl create -f deployment-and-service.yaml`. Is this what you need?

Comment: just didn't find any docs about that specifically, what section? container spec? a new section with same syntax as independently defined service yaml?

Comment: So you can write your deployment manifest (like [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment)) then you can write your service manifest (like [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service#defining-a-service)) and then you can put them in the same file with a `---` between them (like [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques.md#embedding-multiple-documents-in-one-file)). That is part of the YAML spec rather than a kubernetes specific thing

Comment: For an example of how you write the Service so that it matches up with the Deployment, you can look at the definition of the default backend of the nginx ingress controller for inspiration [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/default-backend.yaml)

Comment: I did not know that, wow, In other words, just learn yaml :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your Deployment manifest (like [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment)) then you can write your Service manifest (like [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service#defining-a-service)) and then you can put them in the same file with a `---` between them (like [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques.md#embedding-multiple-documents-in-one-file)). That is part of the YAML spec rather than a Kubernetes specific thing.

For an example of how you can write the Service and Deployment so that they target the same set of Pods, you can look at the definition of the default backend of the nginx ingress controller for inspiration [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/default-backend.yaml).